# Android: Change RelativeLayout backgroundimage with animation like fading

Tags: android, animation

I'm trying to design welcome activity, I need to change *layout activity background image* using animation in **3secs**.

I couldn't find any answer to this problem and I searched the web for this but there is no solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Drawable backgrounds[] = new Drawable[2];

    backgrounds[0] =ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.back_company1, null);
    backgrounds[1] = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.white, null);

   crossfader = new TransitionDrawable(backgrounds);
   welcome_parent.setBackgroundDrawable(crossfader);
   crossfader.startTransition(2500);
```